# Why can I not access columns by name?

Tags: postgresql, libpqxx

Sample code:

```cxx
pqxx::connection c("user=postgres");
pqxx::work txn(c);
pqxx::result r = txn.exec("SELECT d.datname as \"Name\","
       "pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as \"Owner\","
       "pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as \"Encoding\","
       "d.datcollate as \"Collate\","
       "d.datctype as \"Ctype\","
       "pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\\n') AS \"Access privileges\""
       "   FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d"
       "   ORDER BY 1");
try {
  for(int rownum=0; rownum<r.size(); ++rownum ) {
    const pqxx::result::tuple row = r[rownum];
    std::cout << "Column 0 Name: \'" << row[0].name() << "\': " << row[0].c_str() << std::endl;
    const std::string s = "Name";
    std::cout << (row[0].name() == s) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dbname: \'" << row[s].c_str() << "\'" << std::endl; // Exception here
  }
} catch(const pqxx::argument_error &e) {
  std::cout << "Argument Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

My output is as follows

```
Column 0 Name: 'Name': mydb
1
Argument Error: Unknown column name: 'Name'
```

The first columns name is "Name" and testing the rows name against the string "Name" produces a true statement.  But when I access it by that string, i get an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, completely asinine.  You have to quote the name if you want things like uppercase to work.

So changing

```
const std::string s = "Name";
```

to

```
const std::string s = "\"Name\"";
```

fixes the problem.  Apparently, the C interface lowercases what you call it, but doesn't lowercase the fields its testing against.  ARG!  I had to go through the libpqxx code to figure that out.

Comment: That has nothing to do with libpq. That's the standard rule for identifiers in SQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's true for SQL identifiers in evaluated SQL statements, but client interfaces are free to define their own case handling. In many ways it may make more sense to be case-sensitive and case-preserving when handling things like result set column names. Personally I think `libpqxx`'s behaviour here is unhelpful.

Comment: My point is that either, #1 the interface should not do anything to it, so name and Name do not match, but Name and Name match and, name and name match, or #2, it should lowercase the field names as well BEFORE testing, so that Name = name, name = Name, name = name, Name = Name.  The fact that Name and Name can never match is pretty confusing.  The ONLY thing that can go into a PQfnumber() function IS A FIELD NAME, so it should treat as is or do full case folding on everything.